# System.arraycopy problems

Tags: java, arrays

I'm preparing a oca certification 1Z0-803 exam and during some mock tests I encounterd the following question:

```
 int[] scores = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
 System.arraycopy(scores, 2, scores, 3, 3);
 for(int i :  scores) 
    System.out.print(i);
```

I thought that the correct answer could be 123345, but instead it isn't not true because the correct anserw is 123456. I read many times the java doc about this method, but I not able to understart why I'getting this result.
Some suggestion about this?

**UPDATE 1**
After my update the correct answer is 123456. The difference is that in this case the source array and the destination array is the same. From java doc: *If the src and dest arguments refer to the same array object, then the copying is performed as if the components at positions srcPos through srcPos+length-1 were first copied to a temporary array with length components and then the contents of the temporary array were copied into positions destPos through destPos+length-1 of the destination array*

Comment: Nope, that *does* print 123346. Sounds like the test answer is just wrong in this case.

Comment: The Correct Answer is **123346** !!!

Comment: you are right buddy. Look at it answer is 123346 https://ideone.com/oxcMom

Comment: Sorry,I was wrong to write a lenght parameter (I updated my question)

Comment: @Skizzo you should not edit the question when some guys are working on it.

Comment: @Skizzo I've edited my answer for your new edit.

Answer (score 3):

You were right, the correct answer is `123346`. I'm not sure where you saw that it should be `123456` but it obviously does not make sense looking at the description of each parameters.

- First argument is the source, `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`
- Second argument is the starting position in the source array.
- Third argument is the destination in which we copy, which is the same as the source in that case.
- Fourth argument starting position in the destination data. It is 3 in that case.
- Final argument is the length of value we want to copy.

---

As per your new edit, once again the correct answer is not `123456` it is `123345` as you expected.